# How to replace pixel data in dicom image with pydicom?

Tags: python, pydicom

I'm trying to replace pixel data in given example image. My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pydicom import dcmread
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_file

fpath = get_testdata_file('CT_small.dcm')
ds = dcmread(fpath)

# replacing rows and columens with new values 
ds.Rows = 200 
ds.Columns = 200 
# replacing pixel data with new image (type: numpy.ndarray)
ds.pixel_array = data[layer].tobytes()
...
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

---

UPDATE

Ok, if I use

```
ds.PixelData = data[layer].tobytes()
```

instead of

```
ds.pixel_array = data[layer].tobytes()
```

I get an image, but it looks totally different from the original image (data[layer]). What am I missing?

Comment: And in which line is the error?

Comment: Sorry. In line 10: ds.pixel_array = data[layer].tobytes()

Comment: Most likely the data is not in the expected format. If you use CT data, the data is expected to be monochrome, with 2 bytes per pixel. You may have to convert or reshape your numpy array accordingly. As we don't have information about the data you try to set, this is only a guess.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right there. The new data is float32 in 200x200. I did adjust the Rows and Columns. Adding .astype(np.float16) did the Job. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This fixes my problem:

```
ds.PixelData = data[layer].astype(np.float16).tobytes()
```